# T-SQL OUTPUT clause to update a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a utility script that is used to insert data into tables in my database. The script has a number of temp table in it that stores the new data to be inserted and a lot of it is related.

So, for example I have tables like so

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
Table1ID INT
Table1Description VARCHAR(50)
Table1Code VARCHAR(5)
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
Table2ID INT
Table2Description VARCHAR(50)
Table2Code VARCHAR(5)
)

DECLARE @Relationships TABLE
(
Table1Code VARCHAR(5)
Table2Code VARCHAR(5)
)
```

So the script populates the data in @Table1 and @Table2, but doesn't populate the ID fields. Once the data has been MERGEd into the database tables, I update the Table1ID and Table2ID fields in a separate statement as they are auto incrementing fields. Then when I use the @Relationships table to populate the database table, I can join to @Table1 and @Table2 to get the actual ID values.

I'm updating the script and I'm wondering if I can MERGE the data from @Table1/@Table2 into the database and update the ID fields in the temp table as part of the MERGE statement using the OUTPUT clause all in one statement?

I think the answer is no as I can't find anything mentioning updating an existing table with the OUTPUT clause, only inserting into a table.

I am still able to do what I need to do, so I'm not after alternatives. I just wondering if it is possible using the OUTPUT Clause

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you've already checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The result of an `OUTPUT` clause would needs to be captured in a temp table or table variable before it can be used in a subsequent `UPDATE`

Comment: Also, because it looks like you're using the `MERGE` statement, I'll add the [obligatory warnings](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) about the dangers of `MERGE`

Comment: Yeah, I read the documentation and i didn't think I could it, but I wanted to consult the hive mind to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding. The dangers of the MERGE statement don't really apply here. These are maintenance scripts used to update configuration or list data out of hours and very basic in operation. None of the tables have triggers